# Angular 6 / Typescript - How do I check if there's a single digit in a variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this value:

`this.value.day`

It returns a number from 1 to 31.

However, I'd like to insert a 0 if it's less than 10, how can I do that?

Comment: You can use `padStart` from the String prototype: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pad a value with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One liner and cross browser compatible

```
newValue = ('0' + this.value.day.toString()).slice(-2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not an elegant solution, but it gets the job done.

```
if (this.value.day < 10) {
  this.dayRender = "0" + this.value.day;
} else {
  this.dayRender = this.value.day;
}
```